# Remove an extra directory in Wordpress with .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, wildcard

I'm not sure what happened, but for some reason my blog started directing only some links on my blog to a duplicate directory. For some reason only some of the links are getting an extra **/blog/** to the url string resulting in

wrong example - http://mywebsite.com**/blog/** blog/my-page/

rather than

right example - http://mywebsite.com/blog/my-page/

So now I'm pulling 404 errors all over the place.

How do I go about writing a string that will remove the extra directory "/blog/" from the middle of my url? Is there a wildcard approach I can use?

Answer (score 1):

one solution is to add .htaccess like:

```
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} blog/blog
RewriteRule ^(.*)blog/blog(.*)$ $1blog$2 [QSA,L]
```

but what you should probably be looking for are relative links in your blog pages, links like 'blog/something' because these will cause links from blog pages to look for an additional subdirectory called blog.

Comment: Right. Essentially what I want to do is remove the extra "blog" reference in the middle. There are trailing titles included after blog.

http://mywebsite.com/blog/my-page/

I'm not quite sure why it started showing up in the first place. There must have been a plugin update I suppose. I haven't added anything new for a while. It's possible this has been happening longer than I realized.